# join strings differently when one is empty

Tags: javascript, string, join

I want to use a method in two situation. Once with 2 and once with 3 arguments. When I execute the code with 2 arguments, it gives me: `Mobile app - undefined` because the `chosenProgram` argument is empty. How can I modify the statement, when I want in case of empty argument input without `- undefined` ?

```
switchStatement: function(typeCode, chosenType, chosenProgram) {

        switch (typeCode) {
            case 1:
                this.config.form__internet.find('input').val(chosenType  + ' - ' + chosenProgram);
                break;
            case 2:
                this.config.form__tv.find('input').val(chosenType + ' - ' + chosenProgram);
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Add `chosenProgram = chosenProgram || ''` at the beginning of method.

Comment: ES6: `function(typeCode, chosenType, chosenProgram = "") {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want the dash, format the string beforehand:

```
var result = chosenType + (chosenProgram ? (' - ' + chosenProgram): "");
```

and then use the formatted string:

```
this.config.form__internet.find('input').val(result );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `chosenProgram` value in a different var depending on its arguments.

```
switchStatement: function(typeCode, chosenType, chosenProgram) {
        var chosen = choseProgram === undefined ? "" : chosenProgram;
        switch (typeCode) {
            case 1:
                this.config.form__internet.find('input').val(chosenType  + ' - ' + chosen);
                break;
            case 2:
                this.config.form__tv.find('input').val(chosenType + ' - ' + chosen);
                break;
        }
}
```